# how to create tables on azure and connect them with VS2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I have built my MVC 5 project with a database using entity framework db first. I published my website but had problems with my database.after lots of research to solve the problem,i figured to build my database on azure since it's only 2 tables and copied the connection string to the web.config file on my MVC 5 project.
when publishing again with the new connection string update, an error showed indicating that can't find the database:

```
The system cannot find the file specified
```

**Exception Details:** System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

This is what the azure offered me as a connection String:

```
Server=tcp:idud662mdp.database.windows.net,1433;Database=sportsMArAiCkhuw;User ID=sportsMania@idud662mdp;Password={your_password_here};Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;
```

I have modified it and this is my connectionString:

```
<add name="DataEntryNew" connectionString ="Data Source=idud662mdp.database.windows.net;Database=sportsMArAiCkhuw;User ID=sportsMania@idud662mdp;Password=My-Pass;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: Can you please provide a code snippet of where this exception is thrown?

Comment: when I run the website from azure, If I want to add data to the database (create) it's throwing this exception so I can't access the database on azure

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string is not the same one as provided by Azure. Try changing the `DataEntryNew` tag in the web.config file to:

```
<add name="DataEntryNew" connectionString ="Server=tcp:idud662mdp.database.windows.net,1433;Database=sportsMArAiCkhuw;User ID=sportsMania@idud662mdp;Password={your_password_here};Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```